# Query result giving out more than it should

Tags: php, pdo, sizeof

I have this code in my class:

```
public function get_data(){
        $sql = "select id_especialidad, descripcion from especialidad";
        foreach($this->dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
                $this->rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $this->rows;
}
```

Now I use it from HTML file like this:

```
<select>
    <?php
        $datos = $db->get_data();
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($datos);$i++)
        {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $datos[$i]["id_especialidad"]?>"><?php echo $datos[$i]["descripcion"]?></option>
           <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

---

Now in the browser I see the select with the rows but in the first row is says: "Notice: Undefined index: descripcion in (file_path)"

I have 9 rows in my table but when I put this "print sizeof($datos)" it shows 11 rows.

What is happening?

is there another way to show this data?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you inspect the array? `print_r($datos)` to see what it contains.

Comment: Reduce some confusion with a `foreach` loop. An incremental `for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($datos);$i++)` loop is rarely needed in PHP. You could be using `foreach ($datos as $d) { echo $d['id_especialidad'];... }`

Comment: Can we see your `query` function in the database class? Maybe it is fetching your results as `fetch_row` and you're trying to use it as `fetch_assoc` or `fetch_array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know where and how you're using or re-using `$this->rows[]` as you haven't posted about it, I will change a bit your code:

```
public function get_data()
{
    $sql = "SELECT id_especialidad, 
                   descripcion 
              FROM especialidad";
    $result = array();
    foreach($this->dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        $result = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Given **`$this->dbh->query`** is the [**`PDO query`**](http://www.php.net/pdo.query), if you `print_r` the result you get from `get_data` it should give you something similar to:

```
Array(
    [0]=>Array([id_especialidad]=>1
                             [0]=>1
                   [descripcion]=>test
                             [1]=>test
              )
    [1]=>Array([id_especialidad]=>2
                             [0]=>2
                   [descripcion]=>test2
                             [1]=>test2
              )
     )
```

And you can easily read it like this:

```
<select>
<?php
$data = $db->get_data();
foreach ($data as $item)
{
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $item["id_especialidad"]; ?>"><?php echo $item["descripcion"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

**If you're getting more than 9 results where it should have been only 9 I can only think there might be a problem with `$this->rows[]` not being cleared after used or something alike.**

Comment: Thanks a Lot! You were right!! It was the array $this->rows[]. I use it at every query but forgot initialize it before using it. You're the best!